# Reset CouchDB completely

Tags: macos, http, couchdb, http-delete, data-persistence

For the purposes of unit testing, I'd like to be able to *completely* remove documents and databases from a CouchDB instance running on my mac. Deleting the standard way isn't really a reset, which is not ideal for unit tests. I need to completely reset the environment.

I've found that deleting the `~/Library/Application Support/CouchDB` directory resets the database to "Admin Party" and deletes all records, which is what I want. But, is there a cleaner, more flexible way to get a clean CouchDB instance on macOS?

Comment: I would delete the files that are under the path in the configuration under "database_dir". But the database needs to be stopped before deletion and then started again afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Uninstall CouchDB
- Delete all remaining files (including the data directory)
- Install CouchDB

This can be automated and is probably the best way to ensure a complete reset.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with it not starting at all running this in a console deleted all my data but got it going again

`rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/CouchDB2`